# hist2d using imported data from pandas: "too many values to unpack"

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'd like to plot a `hist2d` plot based on frequency using `x` and `y` data imported using `iloc`. However I keep getting the error:

> ValueError: too many values to unpack

I've shown a picture of the type of figure I'm trying to produce along with my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


xls = pd.ExcelFile('test.xlsx')
df1 = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name='Sheet1', skiprows=1)

x = df1.iloc[[2]]
y = df1.iloc[[3]]

plt.figure(figsize = (10, 6), dpi = 80)
plt.rcParams["font.family"] = "Times New Roman"
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 12})

CPT13 =plt.hist2d(x,y, bins=(50, 50), cmap=plt.cm.jet)
 
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) is given a *list* of index(es), it returns a 2D DataFrame:

  ```
  x = df1.iloc[[2]] # list indexer [2] returns 3rd row as 2D DataFrame
  y = df1.iloc[[3]]
  ```
- But [`hist2d`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d.html) expects `x` and `y` each to be 1D arrays, which causes the error.

  > `x`, `y`: array-like, shape `(n,)`

---

To extract the 3rd and 4th columns, use:

```
x = df1.iloc[:, 2] # colon indexer specifies all rows
y = df1.iloc[:, 3]
```

To extract the 3rd and 4th rows, use:

```
x = df1.iloc[2] # single brackets
y = df1.iloc[3]
```